# How to translate "The Eye of Sauron is always watching" to Black Speech?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, languages

How would the following sentence be translated to Black Speech: "*The Eye of Sauron is always watching*"? Or, more simply, "*Sauron is always watching*", or, even more simply, "*Sauron is watching*"?

And how would it be written in Tengwar?

As I try to translate the words:

- eye - *hont*,
- Sauron - *Shakhbûrz*.
- always - *ûkil*.
- watch - *hon*- , *gon*-.

I used [this Black Speech online translator](http://www.blackspeech.ru/los/index.php?page=5), but I don't know how to make full sentences from it and how to write it.

Comment: This might work as a question here, else try [conlang.se].

Comment: Auga ob sauron kul mab lat ... from ... Eye of Sauron is on you

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that according to Aragorn, Sauron doesn't use the Elf-runes, nor does he use his right name or permit it to be spelled or spoken - in case that's relevant to your need for this.

Comment: @LAK he used them on the Ring. Sauron also isn't his "right" name. That would be Mairon.

Comment: The quote was referring to the S-rune on the Isengard orcs' helms, so apparently Aragorn was referring to the 'Sauron' name in the quote.  But of course when you're the Dark Lord, you don't have to be consistent.

Comment: This was subsequently asked and answered on ConLang, in case anyone comes across it here and wants to follow. https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/1587/how-to-translate-to-black-speech-this-sentence-eye-of-the-sauron-is-always-watc

Comment: @FredricShope - The answer there fails to mention that the website it's taking everything from is all fan information. None of that is Tolkien's language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### That phrase cannot be translated into Tolkien's Black Speech because Tolkien never created translations for any of those words.

Tolkien created a grand total of [around 32 words of Black Speech](https://eldamo.org/content/word-indexes/words-bs.html). None of the words in any variation of the sentences that you are asking to translate were ever rendered into Black Speech by Tolkien.

The closest I can find is `gimb-` "to seek out, to discover", which appears in *ash nazg gimbatul*, "one ring to find them". Maybe that can work for you for "watching".

All of the examples of Black Speech words that you listed in your question are not actual Black Speech words, but fan creations.